# Point systemctl to use variables from a file

Tags: services, systemd, upstart, systemctl

I'm using `systemctl` to launch and keep my app alive. Below is my `.service` file. Notice the `Environment='METEOR_SETTINGS={"privateKey": "ohnoyouseemyprivatekey!"}'`. This is where I will be storing private keys and I wish to not put it visible in this location.

My question is, how exactly do I ask systemctl to read it from a file in a specific location in

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/wow-doge/experimental/wow_doge_builds/bundle/main.js
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=logdoge
#User=root
#Group=root
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
Environment=PORT=3000
Environment=HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT=1
Environment=MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/wow-doge
Environment=ROOT_URL=https://localhost
Environment='METEOR_SETTINGS={"privateKey": "ohnoyouseemyprivatekey!"}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html#environmentfile-directive

> EnvironmentFile similar to Environment directive but reads the environment variables from a text file. The text file should contain new-line-separated variable assignments.

Example:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/envfile
```

Contents of `/etc/envfile`:

```
NODE_ENV=production
PORT=3000
HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT=1
MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/wow-doge
ROOT_URL=https://localhost
METEOR_SETTINGS={"privateKey": "ohnoyouseemyprivatekey!"}
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked as intended!

Comment: Also `man systemd.directives` lists all the directives. Search for "environment" in that list also surfaces `EnvironmentFile=`.